# Role of servlet context,set attribute and request dispatcher in servlets program

Tags: servlets

```
ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
sc.setAttribute("UserName", str1);
```

what is the role of these codes in servlets.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code

```
ServletContext sc=getServletContext();
sc.setAttribute("UserName", str1);
```

This is to set the value of str1 to the "UserName" attribute and the value can be used in the entire application in servlets or JSP's wherever needed.Setting the attribute to the context makes sure that the attribute value is available and accessible in the entire application